# jquery selector unable to find visible last-child

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="dataTable" class="xLookup">
   <thead id="PickerTHEAD">
      <tr>
         <th class="xSelBox">&nbsp;</th>
         <th style="display: none">Option ID</th>
         <th>My Description</th>
         <th>QTY</th>
         <th>Unit Price</th>
         <th style="display: none">nj1</th>
         <th style="display: none">nj2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         ...
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      ...
   </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is my jquery selector:

```
$( "table#dataTable.xLookup thead#PickerTHEAD tr th:visible:last-child" )
```

I am expecting it to find the **last visible** `th` within `PickerTHEAD` (which would be `<th>Unit Price</th>`), but it finds nothing.

If I change my selector to remove the `:visible` like so...

```
$( "table#dataTable.xLookup thead#PickerTHEAD tr th:last-child" )
```

...then it finds `<th style="display: none">nj2</th>` as expected.

What am I doing wrong? How can I select the last visible `th`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey The answers there are all pretty poor, none of them explain the problem or why their solutions work.

Comment: ... Then answer that question with a better answer... Or use your gold badge to make that one a dupe of this one.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Done! `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`.last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) selector:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the final one in the set.

```
$( "table#dataTable.xLookup thead#PickerTHEAD tr th:visible" ).last()
```

Because your last visible child is **not last child** in the DOM node.

```js
var a = $( "table#dataTable.xLookup thead#PickerTHEAD tr th:visible" ).last();

console.log(a.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable" class="xLookup">
   <thead id="PickerTHEAD">
      <tr>
         <th class="xSelBox">&nbsp;</th>
         <th style="display: none">Option ID</th>
         <th>My Description</th>
         <th>QTY</th>
         <th>Unit Price</th>
         <th style="display: none">nj1</th>
         <th style="display: none">nj2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         ...
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      ...
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `:last-child` [Selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) which selects all elements that are the last child of their parent.

You will need to use `:last` [Selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) that selects the last matched element.

```js
th = $("table#dataTable.xLookup thead#PickerTHEAD tr th:visible:last");

console.log(th.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable" class="xLookup">
  <thead id="PickerTHEAD">
    <tr>
      <th class="xSelBox">&nbsp;</th>
      <th style="display: none">Option ID</th>
      <th>My Description</th>
      <th>QTY</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th style="display: none">nj1</th>
      <th style="display: none">nj2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```